# Why is OrientDB not using the right index?

Tags: database, indexing, orientdb

I have the following indices set up on a class in orientDB:

```
INDEXES (3 altogether)
-------------------------------+----------------+
 NAME                          | PROPERTIES     |
-------------------------------+----------------+
 opponentId                    | accountId (+)  |
                               | opponentId     |
 noiseId                       | noiseId        |
 protocolId                    | accountId (+)  |
                               | protocolId     |
```

and I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
 explain select * from method where accountId=1 and protocolId=1 and noiseId=1
```

I got weird results:

1) Instead of using the ''noiseId'' index or the ''protocolId'' index, orient chose to use the ''opponentId'' index

2) Here's explain's raw output:

```
{
    "@type": "d",
    "@version": 0,
    "fullySortedByIndex": false,
    "compositeIndexUsed": 1,
    "involvedIndexes": ["opponentId"],
    "limit": -1,
    "fetchingFromTargetElapsed": 0,
    "indexIsUsedInOrderBy": false,
    "elapsed": 0.195936,
    "resultType": "collection",
    "resultSize": 0,
    "@fieldTypes": "compositeIndexUsed=l,involvedIndexes=e,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,elapsed=f"
}
```

3) All the fields here are numbers (accountId=long and the rest are integers). The index is of type SBTREE and is NOTUNIQUE

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? Can someone shed some light on OrientDB's indexing logic?

Comment: Hi, what type / types of index are you using ?

Comment: The field types are all numbers (accountId is long, the rest are integers)
The index types are all SBTREE and are NOTUNIQUE

Comment: Sorry, I was posting the answer and I haven't seen your message. I used an UNIQUE index but the concept should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your case with this structure:

```
select from Method

----+-----+------+---------+-------+----------+----------
#   |@RID |@CLASS|accountId|noiseId|opponentId|protocolId
----+-----+------+---------+-------+----------+----------
0   |#21:0|Method|0        |0      |0         |0
1   |#21:1|Method|4        |4      |4         |4
2   |#21:2|Method|8        |8      |8         |8
3   |#22:0|Method|1        |1      |1         |1
4   |#22:1|Method|5        |5      |5         |5
5   |#22:2|Method|9        |9      |9         |9
6   |#23:0|Method|2        |2      |2         |2
7   |#23:1|Method|6        |6      |6         |6
8   |#24:0|Method|3        |3      |3         |3
9   |#24:1|Method|7        |7      |7         |7
----+-----+------+---------+-------+----------+----------
```

and these are my **indexes**:

```
NAME         |   TYPE      |  FIELDS                          
-------------|-------------|----------------------------
opponentId   |   UNIQUE    |  ["accountId","opponentId"]
noiseId      |   UNIQUE    |  ["noiseId"]                 
protocolId   |   UNIQUE    |  ["accountId","protocolId"]
```

If I execute your query

```
explain select * from method where accountId=1 and protocolId=1 and noiseId=1
```

effectivly only the `opponentId` is shown

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "documentReads": 1,
        "fullySortedByIndex": false,
        "compositeIndexUsed": 1,
        "current": "#22:0",
        "documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass": 1,
        "recordReads": 1,
        "involvedIndexes": [
            "opponentId"
        ],
        "limit": -1,
        "fetchingFromTargetElapsed": 0,
        "indexIsUsedInOrderBy": false,
        "evaluated": 1,
        "elapsed": 1.696754,
        "resultType": "collection",
        "resultSize": 1,
        "@fieldTypes": "documentReads=l,compositeIndexUsed=l,current=x,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass=l,recordReads=l,involvedIndexes=e,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,evaluated=l,elapsed=f"
    }
],
"notification": "Query executed in 0.047 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
```

}

In this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/f7bd3s4f3Jo seems that the OrientDB query executor cannot manage multiple indexes in the usage of multiple `AND` conditions, but you can use a `LET` statement in your query to use the indexes correctly.

**Query**:

```
select expand(intersect($a,$b,$c))
let $a = (select from Method where accountId=1),
    $b = (select from Method where protocolId=1),
    $c = (select from Method where noiseId=1)
```

**Output**:

```
----+-----+------+---------+-------+----------+----------
#   |@RID |@CLASS|accountId|noiseId|opponentId|protocolId
----+-----+------+---------+-------+----------+----------
0   |#22:0|Method|1        |1      |1         |1
----+-----+------+---------+-------+----------+----------
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi anonybunny, did you have a chance to try the query ?